# Drag each element separately

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a gadget system in javascript like Win7 Sidebar, but I can use only one element. If I use two, all elements can have the same position or don't work. I need can use more than one elements and drag each one separately (each one with his particular positions).

I have only one element. How can I turn this to work with more than one?

```js
var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
    x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
    x_elem = 0, y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

// Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
    // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
    selected = elem;
    x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
    y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
}

// Will be called when user dragging an element
function _move_elem(e) {
    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
    y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
    if (selected !== null) {
        selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
        selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
    }
}

// Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
    selected = null;
}

// Bind the functions...
document.getElementById('draggable-element').onmousedown = function () {
    _drag_init(this);
    return false;
};

document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
document.onmouseup = _destroy;
```

```css
body {padding:10px}

#draggable-element {
  width:125px;
  height:125px;
  background-color:#666;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 12px;
  cursor:move;
  position:relative; /* important (all position that's not `static`) */
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/DaniellMesquito/yx0dzfjd/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note:

1. If you want to do something on multiple elements you need to either use `class`'s or `tag`s.
2. In your `_drag_init()` function, you set the `x_elem` and `y_elem` equal to `x_pos` and `y_pos` which are changed in you `_move_elem()` function. So it add's in the current positioning to the elements offset. So just get rid of the `selected.Offset`

However, there are still some other calculation issues that you need to work out

```js
var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
    x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
    x_elem = 0, y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

// Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
    // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
    selected = elem;
    x_elem = x_pos ;
    y_elem = y_pos;
}

// Will be called when user dragging an element
function _move_elem(e) {
    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
    y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
    if (selected !== null) {
        selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
        selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
    }
}

// Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
    selected = null;
}

// Bind the functions...
var draggables = document.getElementsByClassName('draggable-element');
for(var i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++){
  draggables[i].onmousedown = function () {
      _drag_init(this);
      return false;
  };
}

document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
document.onmouseup = _destroy;
```

```css
body {padding:10px}

.draggable-element {
  width:125px;
  height:125px;
  background-color:#666;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 12px;
  cursor:move;
  position:relative; /* important (all position that's not `static`) */
}
```

```html
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
```